# Why is the child collection is null in One-To-Many relationship of spring boot application?

Tags: spring, jpa, configuration, datasource

I create a spring boot application with MySQL,JPA,Web dependencies,and manually config my database settings in .properties file of Spring boot. I passed compiling, and started application successfully, and adding one record is normal fine.

BUT, i use method 'findAll(Pageable pageable)' i got a problem, that was

```
Could not write JSON: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role，could not initialize proxy - no Session
```

I got confused, i started to debug my code, finally i found that the child collection of the result is null, and it contained an error, which is

```
"Exception occurred: com.sun.jdi.InvocationException occurred invoking method.."
```

I tried a lot to fix my code, but no use.
who can help me?

**The entity relationship is a simple one to many:**
TeacherInfo entity and ClassInfo entity, teacher manage multiple classes, just simple as this.

**here is the enter point of my app:**

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude= {
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class,
        HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class,
        DataSourceAutoConfiguration.class
})
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class OrmTestApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(OrmTestApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**Database properties setting is here:**

```
spring.datasource.primary.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ormtest?useSSL=false
spring.datasource.primary.username=root
spring.datasource.primary.password=BlaNok2700
spring.datasource.primary.driver-class-name = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto = update
hibernate.show-sql = true
```

**My Data base configure java code is here:**

```
Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "com.lanjian.ormtest.repositories", entityManagerFactoryRef = "primaryEntityManagerFactory", transactionManagerRef = "primaryTransactionManager")
public class PrimaryDbConfig {

@Autowired
private Environment env;

@Bean
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix="spring.datasource.primary")
public DataSourceProperties primaryDataSourceProperties() {
    return new DataSourceProperties();
}

@Bean
public DataSource primaryDataSource() {
    DataSourceProperties dbProperty = primaryDataSourceProperties();
    return DataSourceBuilder.create()
            .driverClassName(dbProperty.getDriverClassName())
            .url(dbProperty.getUrl())
            .username(dbProperty.getUsername())
            .password(dbProperty.getPassword())
            .build();
}

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean primaryEntityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    factory.setDataSource(primaryDataSource());
    factory.setPackagesToScan("com.lanjian.ormtest.entities");
    factory.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());

    Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", env.getProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto"));
    jpaProperties.put("hibernate.show-sql", env.getProperty("hibernate.show-sql"));
    factory.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);
    return factory;
}

@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager primaryTransactionManager() {
    EntityManagerFactory factory = primaryEntityManagerFactory().getObject();
    return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
}
```

}

**My REST controller method is here:**

```
@Autowired
private TeacherRepository teacherRepository;

@GetMapping("/page")
public Page<TeacherInfo> page(Pageable pageable){
    Page<TeacherInfo> list = teacherRepository.findAll(pageable);
    return list;
}
```

**What happened**
After i started my application, and use postman send request, i got this:
[got a 500 error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoOzQ.png)

**And i debugger my code, found this:**
[child collection is null](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O15Xz.png)
In the picture, 'classes' is a list collection, but it is null, i don't understand.

**Here are the TeacherInfo entity I defined**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "teacher")
public class TeacherInfo {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String name;

private byte age;

private boolean male;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="chargedTeacher")
private List<ClassInfo> classes = new ArrayList<>();

public void initialize() {
    for (ClassInfo classInfo : classes) {
        classInfo.setChargedTeacher(this);
        for (StudentInfo studentInfo : classInfo.getStudents()) {
            studentInfo.setClassInfo(classInfo);
        }
    }
}
//Setters and Getters}
```

**Here is the ClassInfo Entity i defined**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "class_info")
 public class ClassInfo {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

private String name;

private int capacity;

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "teacher_id",nullable=false)
@JsonIgnore
private TeacherInfo chargedTeacher;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,fetch=FetchType.LAZY,mappedBy="classInfo")
private List<StudentInfo> students = new ArrayList<>();

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public int getCapacity() {
    return capacity;
}

public void setCapacity(int capacity) {
    this.capacity = capacity;
}

public TeacherInfo getChargedTeacher() {
    return chargedTeacher;
}

public void setChargedTeacher(TeacherInfo chargedTeacher) {
    this.chargedTeacher = chargedTeacher;
}

public List<StudentInfo> getStudents() {
    return students;
}

public void setStudents(List<StudentInfo> students) {
    this.students = students;
}
```

}

Comment: you can indicate on classes field @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER ..

Comment: I tried, but the result of returning is not expected, there is only one record in table, but i got 4 from the response, the 4 records are the same, too strange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem may come from Transactionality and JPA Fetching types.

Your repository method is being invoked not using a transaction, which implies that the transaction is on the boundaries of the method invocation (which might not be wrong). Spring returns a Page with objects but when it tries to serialize them, transaction is gone so no way to access childs.

I would suggest to put the JPA relationship as EAGER fetching, allowing all the objects to be present on the repository result when the transaction ends.

EDIT:
    Answer to comments
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager primaryTransactionManager(EntityManagerFactory factory) {
        return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
    }

Comment: I tried to change the EAGER fetching, but the result of returning is not expected, there is only one record in table, but i got 4 from the response, the 4 records are the same, too strange...

Comment: That seems to be a JPA mapping error. Could you please provide those 2 Entities and their mapping?

Comment: I recreate another application, but in this version, i don't config the datasource manually, I use Spring boot auto configuration mechanism, the entity fetching type is still Lazy, and, the response is right and normal. why? I think i made some mistakes in configuring the datasource, but i don't know where it is. And I still want to manually config the datasource, cus, it is possible in the future, i'll connect two data sources, so, manually config would be helpful.

Comment: Yes, i updated my post, plz review my post, I posted the TeacherInfo entity and ClassInfo entity.

Comment: Could i send my code package to you by Email? it is an Experiment project for testing functionality of Spring boot.

Comment: @Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager primaryTransactionManager() {
    EntityManagerFactory factory = primaryEntityManagerFactory().getObject();
    return new JpaTransactionManager(factory);
} This might be the source of the problem

Comment: the initialize method is used for Child pointed to parent, cuz, the relationship is bidirectional binding, if not do so, I can't do persist or merge operation for child collection.

Comment: The getObject should not be used. Add the EntityManagerFactory as a parameter to the method

Comment: wooooooooooooooooooooow, yes! i shouldn't use the getObject() method. Things gonna worked!!!!! Thank you very much!